# Post with javascript or jQuery (NOT AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to post with javascript or jQuery (not via ajax, by the same way as form i posted) without creating form element? How?

Comment: What's the use case? Why would you not be able to use Ajax or a form element?

Comment: You would have to create a form element and fill it with something, otherwise there's nothing to post?

Comment: I need to post with redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cannot make a POST request without using a `<form />` tag, without using AJAX.

Comment: No problem. If you post another question about exactly what the issue is, and why you can't use a form tag or AJAX, we may be able to help.